# How many binary strings of length $n$ contain $k$ flips?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have say the string $1010010001010101$, which has a length of $16$ and there are $12$ flips. My thoughts are to just count the number of ways I can stick a $10$ in the there so ${n-1 \choose 0.5k}$ but I know that doesn't account for the times the first and last bits aren't the same and $k$ is odd, or what the bits in between the $10$ are, since they could be a run of $1$s or $0$s.

Been out of school for a couple of years and it's kind of depressing how much I've forgotten, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: When we select a prime $p$ for the multiplicative discrete logarithm in $\mathbb Z_p$ with a generator $g$, the order of $g$ is $p-1$. This is not a prime and if it doesn't have a large prime, i.e. it is a smooth number then the Pohlig-Hellman will rule!

One can choose a prime $p$ and see that it has a large prime factor for the order, however, this is time-consuming for generation and also performance cost of operation. Instead, we can choose safe prime $q$ as $q = 2p+1$ where $p$ is also prime and called the Sophie Germain prime.

Comment: In this case, we can choose a generator $g$ such that it has order $p$. The possible orders are $2,p,$ and $2p$ with the [Lagrange's theorem on Group theory][1]. 

> If H is a subgroup of a group G, then $$ \left|G\right|=\left[G:H\right]\cdot \left|H\right|.$$

It is clear that $-1 = p-1$ has order 2. For a random selection, or starting from the beginning $2,3,4,...$ check that $g^p \equiv =1$. This can be calculated quite fast with modular repeating squaring algorithms, or similar ones.

Now we have an element $g$ that has prime order $p$ is not vulnerable to the Pohlig-Hellman.

Comment: This was the answer of your question in cryptography.SE. You have deleted just before I've click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have $n$ digits, then there are $n-1$ spaces between the digits, of which $k$ are "flips" and the others are not. We have $\binom{n-1}{k}$ ways to position the flips. Additionally, for each of these choices of flip positions, the leftmost digit could be a zero or a one, so we multiply the number of choices by 2 to account for this difference:
$$
2 \binom{n-1}{k}
$$

Comment: "spaces between the digits" ahhhhh, now I remember how I'm supposed to think about it, thanks!